# Aspect Oriented Programming- advice runs in same thread?

Tags: spring-aop

If I have an advice(before, after or around) which will be applicable to a method, will this advice run in the same thread which invokes the method? This is Spring's AOP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it will run in the same thread.  The Aspect will create a proxy of the object method which matches the pointcut definition which will be executed around the method.  But it does not do anything on a different thread.